# Post ID wrong in Functions.php

Tags: php

I am trying to execute the following code inside my functions.php to change the title of my wordpress blog.

```
function filter_pagetitle($url) {

        global $wp_query;

        $the_post_id = $wp_query->post->ID;
        $the_post_data = get_post($the_post_id);

        return $the_post_data->post_title;
}

add_filter('wp_title', 'filter_pagetitle');
```

However, $the_post_id always comes back as the same one, and never changes to the ID of the post that I am viewing?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
function filter_pagetitle($url) {

        global $post;            

        return $post->post_title;
}

add_filter('wp_title', 'filter_pagetitle');
```

Comment: +1 for using $post rather than $wp_query. `$post->ID` should get the ID.